# Get the attributes of a class

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is there any universal way to get the attributes of a class by class name and instance?

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.prop = 1

a = A()

for attr, value in a.__dict__.items():
    print(attr, value) # prop, 1
```

.

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.prop = 1

for attr, value in A.__dict__.items():
    print(attr, value) 
   #__dict__, __doc__, __init__, __module__, __weakref__
```

Why the last example returns `dir` attibutes why the results differ?

Comment: What would you expect that to give you?

Comment: >Is there any universal way to get the attributes of a class by class name and instance? < I didn't understand this

Comment: I mean how to get class attributes in the second example (I want to get `prop, 1`)?

Comment: @Opsa, in your second example you are asking for class attributes, but `prop` exists only in this class instance, that's why it's not there

Comment: `prop` is not a class attribute in your second example. Its still an attribute of an instance.

Comment: Please read http://docs.python.org/py3k/reference/datamodel.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`__dict__, __doc__, __module__, ...` are actually present in a class, even you haven't created them. They are 'built-in'.

So it's normal that `dir` shows them to you.

`__dict__` attribute in an instance stores instance attributes.

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.prop = 1

a = A()
for attr, value in a.__dict__.items():
    print(attr, value)
```

This shows instance attributes. And there is just one instance attribute - `prop` (`self.prop = 1`)

```
for attr, value in A.__dict__.items():
```

And this gets class attributes. `prop` was added to an instance, so it's not here.

See http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#special-attributes

To get from an object all attributes, including class attributes, base class attributes, use [inspect.getmembers](http://docs.python.org/library/inspect.html#inspect.getmembers)

Comment: Thx for your answer, but tell how to get `class` attributes like by instance?